# Getting error "Method is never used" in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods, onclick

Hello I have come across this error within my methods in my code. It is giving out the error "Method is is Never Used"?

MainMenuActivity.java

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Dialog myDialog;

TextView value1;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotmenu);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    value1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value1);


}
```

The Method PopUpMenu enables a pop up screen to show when a button is pressed.

```
public void PopUpMenu(View v) {
    TextView txtClose;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink1);
    txtClose = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose);
    txtClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

I am getting the error for both methods which are the add and minus methods. They are not functionally within the PopUpMenu Method. Do I have to format this a certain way? I have tried putting it outside the main method but the add and minus methods do not work.

```
        public void add(View v){
            count++;
            value1.setText("" + count);
        }

        public void minus(View v){
            if (count <= 0) count = 0;
            count--;
            value1.setText("" + count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```

The Add and Minus Methods are from a layout for the PopUpMenu method

MenuItems.xml

```
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#6E2C00"
            android:onClick="minus"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/value1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#6E2C00"
            android:onClick="add"
            android:text="+" />
```

Full Code For MainMenuActivity.java

```
 package com.example.cafemenubottom;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Dialog myDialog;

TextView value1;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotmenu);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    value1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value1);


}

public void PopUpMenu(View v) {
    TextView txtClose;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink1);
    txtClose = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose);
    txtClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void add(View v){
            count++;
            value1.setText("" + count);
        }

        public void minus(View v){
            if (count <= 0) count = 0;
            count--;
            value1.setText("" + count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
public void PopUpMenu2(View v) {
    TextView txtClose2;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink2);
    txtClose2 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose2);
    txtClose2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
public void PopUpMenu3(View v) {
    TextView txtClose3;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink3);
    txtClose3 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose3);
    txtClose3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
public void PopUpMenu4(View v) {
    TextView txtClose4;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink4);
    txtClose4 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose4);
    txtClose4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
public void PopUpMenu5(View v) {
    TextView txtClose5;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink5);
    txtClose5 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose5);
    txtClose5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
public void PopUpMenu6(View v) {
    TextView txtClose6;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.hotdrink6);
    txtClose6 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtClose6);
    txtClose6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.show();
}
```

}

I'm planning on adding the Minus and Add methods on the other PopMenu methods. Just wanted to test it on tyhe first pop up menu

Comment: Can you show the complete code in MainMenuActivity.java ?

Comment: @oyeraghib sure!

Comment: @oyeraghib I've added the full code

Comment: You are creating `add`, `minus` & `onClick` methods inside another method (`txtClose.setOnClickListener`), which is never going to work. Wither separate them or do the calculations directly as you are only changing the variables & changing text.

Comment: I see. I will need to do something about that. Thank You for your input @DarShan